# Найти максимальное и минимальное значение высоты на terrain(Unity)?

Tags: unity3d, position, max, min, terrain

Возникла потребность поставить флажок, где в точке максимальная и минимальная высота terrain.
Есть ответы как это сделать но они не работают. Мне надо вернуть мин, мак точки  в формате Vector3. Сейчас я делаю так по этому [примеру](https://answers.unity.com/questions/402598/how-to-get-a-terrains-maximum-height.html) :

```
if (flag) {
    if (GUILayout.Button ("Min")) {
        if (TerrainList.Count () == 0) {
            TerrainList = LofP.setTerrain ();
        }
        Vector3 min = default(Vector3);
        float min_height=0;
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var terrain in TerrainList)
        {
            if(count == 0) { 
                min= terrain.terrainData.bounds.min;
                min_height = terrain.terrainData.bounds.min.y;
            } else{
                if(min_height >= terrain.terrainData.bounds.min.y) {
                    min= terrain.terrainData.bounds.min;
                    min_height = terrain.terrainData.bounds.min.y;
                }
            }

        }

        GameObject min_flag = Resources.Load<GameObject> ("Flag/Mesh/flag point");
        min_flag.name = "min_flag";
        Instantiate(min_flag, min, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    if (GUILayout.Button ("Max")) {
        if (TerrainList.Count () == 0) {
            TerrainList = LofP.setTerrain ();
        }
        Vector3 max = default(Vector3);
        float max_height=0;
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var terrain in TerrainList)
        {
            if(count == 0) { 
                max= terrain.terrainData.bounds.max;
                max_height = terrain.terrainData.bounds.max.y;
            } else{
                if(max_height <= terrain.terrainData.bounds.max.y) {
                    max= terrain.terrainData.bounds.max;
                    max_height = terrain.terrainData.bounds.max.y;
                }
            }

        }

        GameObject max_flag = Resources.Load<GameObject> ("Flag/Mesh/flag point");
        max_flag.name = "max_flag";
        Instantiate(max_flag, max, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Но флажки устанавливаются не в тех местах.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    internal bool flag = true;
    internal float verificationStep = 2f;

...
        flag = EditorGUILayout.Foldout (flag, "Min Max height terrain");

        if (flag) {
            verificationStep = EditorGUILayout.Slider ("Шаг проверки",verificationStep, 0.1f, 10f);
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Min")) {
                if (TerrainList.Count () == 0) {
                    TerrainList = LofP.setTerrain ();
                }
                Vector3 min = default(Vector3);
                float min_height=1000;
                int count = 0;
                foreach (var terrain in TerrainList)
                {
                    for (float x =terrain.GetPosition ().x;x<terrain.GetPosition ().x+terrain.terrainData.size.x;x=x+verificationStep) {
                        for (float z =terrain.GetPosition ().z;z<terrain.GetPosition ().z+terrain.terrainData.size.z;z=z+verificationStep) {
                            if(min_height >= terrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(x,0,z))) {
                                min_height = terrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(x,0,z));
                                min = new Vector3(x,min_height,z);
                            }
                         }
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                GameObject min_flag = Resources.Load<GameObject> ("Flag/Mesh/flag point");
                min_flag.name = "min_flag";
                Instantiate(min_flag, min, Quaternion.identity);
            }
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Max")) {
                if (TerrainList.Count () == 0) {
                    TerrainList = LofP.setTerrain ();
                }
                Vector3 max = default(Vector3);
                float max_height=0;
                int count = 0;
                foreach (var terrain in TerrainList)
                {
                    for (float x =terrain.GetPosition ().x;x<terrain.GetPosition ().x+terrain.terrainData.size.x;x=x+verificationStep) {
                        for (float z =terrain.GetPosition ().z;z<terrain.GetPosition ().z+terrain.terrainData.size.z;z=z+verificationStep) {
                            if(max_height <= terrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(x,0,z))) {
                                max_height = terrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(x,0,z));
                                max = new Vector3(x,max_height,z);
                            }
                         }
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                GameObject max_flag = Resources.Load<GameObject> ("Flag/Mesh/flag point");
                max_flag.name = "max_flag";
                Instantiate(max_flag, max, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
```